What did Google change in Chromium version 126 that made my PWA not work on Chromium mobile anymore?
Here's all the browsers I tested:

chromium mobile before v126 (installation button appears, PWA installed successfully)
chromium mobile v126-v131 (only generic homescreen shortcut appears, opens the site in a new tab)
chromium desktop (installation button appears, PWA installed successfully)
firefox mobile (installation button appears, PWA installed successfully)
safari mobile (installation button appears, PWA installed successfully)

PWABuilder doesn't tell me anything useful unfortunately: https://www.pwabuilder.com/reportcard?site=https://rdrama.net
Anyway, my site is here if you wanna test it yourself: https://rdrama.net, any help is genuinely appreciated since I definitely can't solve this mystery alone despite how much I try :marseysad:
manfiest.json
{
    "name": "rDrama",
    "short_name": "rDrama",
    "start_url": "/",
    "display": "standalone",
    "background_color": "#f04bec",
    "theme_color": "#805ad5",
    "description": "rDrama",
    "icons": [
            {
                "src": "/i/rDrama/192.png?x=15",
                "sizes": "192x192",
                "type": "image/png",
                "purpose": "any"
            },
            {
                "src": "/i/rDrama/512.png?x=15",
                "sizes": "512x512",
                "type": "image/png"
            }
    ],
    "screenshots": [
            {
                "src": "/i/rDrama/512.png?x=15",
                "sizes": "512x512",
                "type": "image/png",
                "form_factor": "wide",
                "label": "Home screen showing main navigation and featured content"
            },
            {
                "src": "/i/rDrama/512.png?x=15",
                "sizes": "512x512",
                "type": "image/png",
                "label": "Home screen showing main navigation and featured content"
            }
    ]
}

service_worker.js:
'use strict';

const CACHE_NAME = "offlineCache-v1";
const OFFLINE_URL = "/offline.html?x=15";

self.addEventListener("install", () => {
    const cacheOfflinePage = async () => {
        const cache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
        await cache.add(new Request(OFFLINE_URL, {cache: "reload"}));
    };

    cacheOfflinePage().then(() => {
        this.skipWaiting();
    });
});

self.addEventListener("activate", (event) => {
    const expectedCaches = [CACHE_NAME];

    event.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(keys => Promise.all(
            keys.map(key => {
                if (!expectedCaches.includes(key)) {
                    return caches.delete(key);
                }
            })
        ))
    );
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
    if (event.request.mode === "navigate") {
        event.respondWith((async () => {
            try {
                const preloadResponse = await event.preloadResponse;
                if (preloadResponse) return preloadResponse;

                const networkResponse = await fetch(event.request);
                return networkResponse;
            } catch (error) {
                const cachedResponse = await caches.match(OFFLINE_URL);
                return cachedResponse;
            }
        })());
    }
});

self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    const pushData = event.data.text();
    let data, title, body, url, icon;
    try {
        data = JSON.parse(pushData);
        title = data.title;
        body = data.body;
        url = data.url;
        icon = data.icon;
    } catch(e) {
        title = "Untitled";
        body = pushData;
    }
    const options = {
        body: body,
        data: {url: url},
        icon: icon
    };

    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(title, options)
    );
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (e) => {
    e.notification.close();
    e.waitUntil(clients.matchAll({ type: 'window' }).then((clientsArr) => {
        const hadWindowToFocus = clientsArr.some((windowClient) => windowClient.url === e.notification.data.url ? (windowClient.focus(), true) : false);
        if (!hadWindowToFocus) clients.openWindow(e.notification.data.url).then((windowClient) => windowClient ? windowClient.focus() : null);
    }));
});


One person downvoted, and someone else invited. That seems like a rather extreme (and vindictive) reaction to me.

*upvoted rather.
